# How to get the max count of coherently cells?

Tags: sql

I have following data in my table:

ID - Data

1 - 0
2 - 10
3 - 100
4 - 60
5 - 0
6 - 0
7 - 15
8 - 100
9 - 100
10 - 70
11 - 10
12 - 0
13 - 0

What I want is the max count of rows > 0.

This data shows the energy using of a device in percent of a given total.
What I basicly want to know is: how long is the device "on" the longest timeperiod?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  What are you defining as a "timeperiod?"  Or are you assuming that time increases with the `ID` ?

Comment: Can you please show your expected result?

Comment: @NevilleK If I read correctly, the OP wants to know the length of the longest island for which the device is continously "on" ("on" being defined as having a `Data` value greater than zero.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are expecting result 5 (longest sequence of non-zero numbers) for your example data. You can do that with recursive CTE in Oracle:

```
with testData as (
select '1' id, '0' val from dual
union all
select '2', '10' from dual
union all
select '3', '100' from dual
union all
select '4', '60' from dual
union all
select '5', '0' from dual
union all
select '6', '0' from dual
union all
select '7', '15' from dual
union all
select '8', '100' from dual
union all
select '9', '100' from dual
union all
select '10', '70' from dual
union all
select '11', '10' from dual
union all
select '12', '0' from dual
union all
select '13', '0' from dual
) ,
cte (id, val, sumX) as (
select t.id, val, case when val !=0 then 1 else 0 end from testData t where id = 1
union all
select t.id, t.val,  case when t.val !=0 then sumX+1 else 0 end 
from testData t
inner join cte
    on cte.id = t.id-1  
)
select max(sumx) from cte
```